# In an if statement, Is it possible to put multiple "or" values for the same value easily?

Tags: javascript

Question may be a little weird, so here's what I mean.

Is it possible to write the following code:

`(score == 3) || (score == 10) || (score == 15) || (score == 18) || (score == 20)`

in a way that is faster and easier? That kind of typing gets a little annoying after a while. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `[3, 10, 15, 18, 20].includes(score)`

Comment: score, score, score, score, score. The value (type) assigned to scores is always a number so you can represent it as compound data or in JS, an array. so [n0, n1, n2...]